# StateStore is never added on Spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Any Help how can I add state store on Spring cloud

I always receive this error "nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore myStore is not added yet."

Here is the bean definition however it never works

```
@Bean
  public StoreBuilder storeBuilder() {
    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("mystore");
    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, MyData>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier, Serdes.String(), StreamsSerde.MyDataSerde());
    return storeBuilder;
  }
```

Here is the Serde

```
public static final class MyDataSerde extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<MyData> {
    public MyDataSerde() {
      super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MyData.class));
    }
  }
```

Here is the data class

```
public class MyData {
  private String name;
  private String course;
}
```

Here is the spring cloud dependencies

```
springBootVersion = "2.2.5.RELEASE"
set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR3")

implementation group:"org.springframework.cloud", name: "spring-cloud-stream"
    implementation group: "org.springframework.cloud", name: "spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams"
    implementation group: "org.springframework.cloud", name: "spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to add the store programmatically on this article

```
public void initializeStateStores() throws Exception {
   StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean =
         applicationContext.getBean("&stream-builder-requestListener", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
   StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getObject();
   StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Long>> keyValueStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(stateStoreName), Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long());
   streamsBuilder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);
}
```

https://medium.com/@daniyaryeralin/utilizing-kafka-streams-processor-api-and-implementing-custom-aggregator-6cb23d00eaa7

Comment: If you can share a small application, where it didn't work for your original scenario, we can take a further look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add state stores like this when you have to use the lower level processor or transformer API. Did you try to add the state store to your `process` or `transform` method call? Here is a [test](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsFunctionStateStoreTests.java) that works. Take a look at the `process` call and the way the state stores are passed along.

Comment: Yes, I'm using transform.  The issue is that the store is not created, and the transform doesn't find the store. This is why I always get this error " Invalid topology: StateStore myStore is not added yet."

Comment: what version of spring cloud stream?

Comment: I'm using springCloudVersion  "Hoxton.SR3"